# How can I make my app present quote from an array and then proceed in order through the remaining quotes?

Tags: arrays, swift, view

Part of my app is to provide the user with a random quote about sustainability. I have an array of quotes, but haven't thought about how to present it to the user yet so that they are presented with a quote and then can click the next button to see the next one. The app should also make it so that they can pick up where they left off. For example, if they got to quote 10/80 then the next time they go go the quote section they start on quote 10. I also want users to be able to save each quote. Is an array the best way to do this? Would it be completely wrong to use a new view controller for each quote? I'm very new to all this so any help would be great.

Comment: Since you want to reference the quotes by sequential numbers, an array sounds fine.  On the other hand, "Would it be completely wrong to use a new view controller for each quote?"  Almost certainly!

Comment: I agree with what @PhillipMills has said. Your viewControllers view should be reusable and the data it loads e.g from a viewModel should change each time depending on where you index the array at. A great place to start is to get one quote displaying from an array and work your way up through your requirements. Best of luck! 

Comment: Agree with everything said so far. Would also recommend using Core Data to persist data regarding what quote the user has stopped at.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've gotten it working for the most part by incrementing the value of the array. @SanzioAngeli I'd love to add this feature but know nothing about Core Data other than it stores information locally. Any tips on how to get started with it?

Comment: A google search for "iOS data persistence in swift" will yield some useful articles and tutorials for Core Data specifically. Questions asking for tutorials or product recommendations are generally not considered best use of the SO platform, as they often lead to opinion based / marketing related answers :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update, I so far found the best way to do this in my case was to use a collection view. As you scroll through each cell in the collection view you see a new quote. You also see a unique save button for each quote that can hide when tapped, which also then unhides the "unlike" button.